# Show sections of document based on recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I have a DocuSign template, and currently as a proof of concept, am using the POSTMan samples. I have defined sections of the document, based on the template Roles.

For example, I have a role of, say "Landlord". This user's section should appear when the landlord role receives an envelope with this template. The "Landlord" then first signs their section of the document, and can select an entry from a drop-down list. This drop down list contains two other template roles, say "Renter" and "Lawyer" for example.

If the "Landlord" user selects "Lawyer", then the envelope should be routed to the "Lawyer" template role. Now, the "Landlord" section of the document will be displayed, with their signature and date on it, as read-only. The "Lawyer" section of the document will be displayed for the person in that role to complete. The "Renter" section is hidden.

Then the "Lawyer" role signs the document, and it gets routed to the person in the "Renter" role. In the "Renter" role, both "Landlord" and "Lawyer" sections are displayed, but read-only. The "Renter" can now sign the document in their section.

Is this solution possible? Is there a code example of this (C# or within the Postman solution)?

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign supports sending multiple document to multiple recipients and having different information that every recipient enters. 
However, having collapsible sections as well as conditional content may require you to use some of our Document Generation products from our SpringCM. Currently with the core DocuSign offering you cannot do that.

Comment: OK thanks. What if we we had multiple templates, and based on what the first user selected, could then attach a 2nd template / document to that envelope? Would that be an option?

Comment: potentially, but changing an envelope after it was sent is always subject to our rules about "correct", you cannot for example make changes to the documents that the signers that already signed have acknowledged without voiding the envelope and sending them another one.

Comment: OK, thanks Inbar. That seems more complicated, with the added risk of voiding the envelope and getting stuck in a loop where it sends them another one right afterwards....